Why show no file selected or no item to imported use razor page?
How can I modify the code to work with checkboxes and call PrintCartonLabel only for selected items? It is possible to add a checkbox after selecting items and click the print button, then show no file selected and show no file to be imported?
public class CartonLabelModel : PageModel

{
    public List<CartonItems> ImportedCartonItems {get;set;}


public async void OnGet()
{
    ImportedCartonItems = new List<CartonItems>();
    try
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Carton.txt");

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath,Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            reader.ReadLineAsync();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                var values = line.Split('\t');

                if (values.Length > 0)
                {
                    var shipdate = DateTime.Parse(values[5]).Date;
                        var item = new CartonItems
                        {

                            ShipLocation = values[0],
                            ShipAddress = values[1],
                            DocNo2 = values[2],
                            TotalCarton = values[3],
                            CartonQty = int.Parse(values[4]),
                            ShipDate = shipdate,
                            IsSelected = false                     
                        };

                        ImportedCartonItems.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData["Message"] = $"Error message file : {ex.Message}";
    }

}

private void PrintCartonLabel(List<CartonItems> data)
    {

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
         // print logic here..
        }


According to your description, I suggest you could use tempdata to achieve your requirement, you could set the temadata according to the PrintCartonLabel method result and inside the client show this tempdata to show the message.
More details, you could refer to below example:
public class CartonLabelModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<CartonItems> ImportedCartonItems { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        ImportedCartonItems = new List<CartonItems>();
        try
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Carton.txt");

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    var values = line.Split('\t');

                    if (values.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var shipdate = DateTime.Parse(values[5]).Date;
                        var item = new CartonItems
                        {
                            ShipLocation = values[0],
                            ShipAddress = values[1],
                            DocNo2 = values[2],
                            TotalCarton = values[3],
                            CartonQty = int.Parse(values[4]),
                            ShipDate = shipdate,
                            IsSelected = false
                        };

                        ImportedCartonItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = $"Error message file : {ex.Message}";
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostPrintSelected()
    {
        var selectedItems = ImportedCartonItems?.Where(item => item.IsSelected).ToList();
        if (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            // you could also modify the codes to set the tempdata according to the PrintCartonLabel method's result 
            PrintCartonLabel(selectedItems);
            TempData["Message"] = "Labels printed successfully.";
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "No items selected for printing.";
        }

        return RedirectToPage();
    }

    private void PrintCartonLabel(List<CartonItems> data)
    {
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            // print logic here..
        }
    }
}

public class CartonItems
{
    public string ShipLocation { get; set; }
    public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
    public string DocNo2 { get; set; }
    public string TotalCarton { get; set; }
    public int CartonQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

Razor page:
@page
@model WebApplicationRazorPage.Pages.CartonLabelModel
@{
}
<h2>Carton Labels</h2>

<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Ship Location</th>
                <th>Ship Address</th>
                <th>Doc No</th>
                <th>Total Carton</th>
                <th>Carton Qty</th>
                <th>Ship Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @for(int i =0; i<Model.ImportedCartonItems.Count; i++)
            
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].IsSelected" /></td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].ShipLocation</td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].ShipAddress</td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].DocNo2</td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].TotalCarton</td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].CartonQty</td>
                    <td>@Model.ImportedCartonItems[i].ShipDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                </tr>
            
            }
 
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="PrintSelected">Print Selected</button>
</form>

@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        @TempData["Message"]
    </div>
}

Result:


Hi @Brando Zhang , I tried use your suggestion but show no items selected for printing ?
